# How to prevent a CSS animation from rerunning after a second hover animation

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have an animation when the page load and when you hover over the element. my issue is when the hover animation finishes the first one replays. is there any way to stop/prevent it from replaying?

```css
img {
    height: 40px;
    width: auto;
    position: absolute;
    animation-name: test1;
    animation-duration: 4s;
}
img:hover {
    animation-name: test2;
    animation-duration: 4s;
}
@keyframes test1 {
    from {height: 40px}
    to {height: 80px}
}
@keyframes test2 {
    from {height: 40px}
    to {height: 80px}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <img src="https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/874191575004094524/946077618992738375/grey.png" alt="">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [`animation-iteration-count`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-iteration-count)?

Comment: @HereticMonkey `animation-iteration-count` doesn't apply when the computed `animation:` property is reset when the set of active style-rules changes (e.g. when `:hover` is added or removed) - that causes the count to reset to 0.

Comment: Given this is a simple animation, why not use `transition` instead of `animation`?

Comment: @Dai for the original problem the square had to move positions instad of just sizing up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The `animation-*` properties (like `animation:`, `animation-name:`, `animation-duration:`, etc) are multi-valued properties, just like `background-image`.
- When the effective value of a multi-value property for an element changes (e.g. setting an entirely new `background-image:` or `animation:` when an element already has a multiple values for that property) then CSS will *replace the entire list* of values.
- So if one rule sets `animation-name: foo;` and another (temporarily applied) rule sets `animation-name: bar;` then that counts as removing `foo` and adding `bar`, rather than simply adding `bar` to the existing list of animations.
- And CSS animations (by default) start when they are added, and cannot be controlled after they have been removed.
- So in your case, the `test1` animation restarts because your `:hover` rule **removes** the `test1` animation from `img`'s animation-list (and adds `test2`), and then when the `:hover` state is left the `test1` animation is re-added, which makes it restart the `test1` animation again.

The fix is to **not remove** the `test1` animation from the `:hover` state, like so:

```
    img {
        animation-name: test1;
        animation-duration: 4s;
    }
    img:hover {
        animation-name: test1, test2;
        animation-duration: 4s, 4s;
    }
```

---

Demo:

- I've renamed `test1` to `onLoad` and `test2` to `onHover` and sped-up the animations to 1-2s (from 4s) for clarity.
- The image will rotate on-load, and will increase in size on hover.
- Notice that after you stop hovering the image, it won't rotate again.

```css
img {
    height: 40px;
    width: auto;
    position: absolute;


    animation-name: onLoad;
    animation-duration: 1s;
}
img:hover {
    animation-name: onLoad, onHover;
    animation-duration: 1s, 2s;
}
@keyframes onLoad {
    from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to   { transform: rotate(179deg); }
}
@keyframes onHover {
    from { height: 40px; width: 40px; }
    to   { height: 80px; height: 80px; }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVgz6.png" alt="">
```

Comment: The edit a moment ago greatly increases the complexity of the answer and reduces the clarity of the explanation. I'm not sure why you think it's a good idea to introduce unrelated animations in the answer and an annoyingly bright meme image instead of the non-distracting grey square from OP's code?

Comment: @TylerH The OP's example was using an image hosted on a website not controlled by StackExchange, so that "non-distracting grey square" will eventually be a broken image in a couple of years' time, so I replaced it with an alternative - using whatever image was closest to me on my desktop to save time. As for it being "annoyingly bright", who made you the arbiter of taste for SO answers?

Comment: You may not be aware, but you can upload images from other URLs to SO's Imgur subdomain. Concerns over exactly _how_ distracting your image choice was aside, you haven't addressed the main concern of my comment, which is introducing noise and confusion to the answer that previously was quite well-focused to the code OP had, what code they needed to change, and an explanation of the issue. The incorrectly-used bullet point formatting & new rotation effects (not to mention the image) detract from the quality of this answer. It's such a regression that I felt compelled to remove my upvote.

Comment: @TylerH This is StackOverflow, nothing is stopping you from posting your own answer if you think you can provide a better explanation - similarly, nothing is forcing you to spend your time criticizing my answers.

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow explicitly encourages comments when users have criticism to provide or need to request clarification. Likewise, repetition of answers is typically frowned upon; while your answer is objectively worse now than it was in its original form, it still contains the original, useful solution (which is why I only removed my upvote, rather than changing it to a downvote). Providing that exact same solution n another answer, even without the irrelevant content, would go against the rules of answering, which specify that new answers should provide novel content.

Comment: You're free to disagree with criticism, but you're _not_ free to curtail anyone else's right to provide said criticism. If you don't want anyone to discuss your posts, don't post them. Please keep that in mind for the future.